# How to verify if a variable is numeric/character and transform it accordingly in SAS?

Tags: sas

I am working with many similar datasets from different years in SAS. Depending on the year, variables that measure the same dimension are string or numeric, with no particular pattern across years/datasets. I want to make all datasets with the same variables types, so it makes possible to stack all datasets and easier to do analysis across years.

Is there a way of verifying if a variable is numeric and, if it is, transform it in a string, and also the opposite, veryfying if another variable is a string and, if it is, transform it in numeric?

Here an example of the data, but I have a longer time series and a larger number of variables:

```
data score_2016;
   infile datalines delimiter=','; 
   input student_id $ score $;
   datalines;                      
03414132 , 73.4
00874823 , 58.4
;
run;

data score_2017;
   infile datalines delimiter=','; 
   input student_id $ score ;
   datalines;                      
03414132 , 70.3
00874823 , 60.7
;
run;

data score_2018;
   infile datalines delimiter=','; 
   input student_id score ;
   datalines;                      
03414132 , 77.1
00874823 , 57.5
;
run;

data score_2019;
   infile datalines delimiter=','; 
   input student_id score $;
   datalines;                      
03414132 , 68.3
00874823 , 67.2
;
run;
```

In this example, I want the `id` to be a string and the `score` to be numeric for all datasets. The dataset of 2017 is the only one in the format I want. To transform the variables of other datasets, I am editing one by one, but this is not efficient and time consuming, since I need to manually check the data type for every variable:

```
data score_2016;
set score_2016 (rename=(score=old_score));
score = input(old_score, 8.);
drop old_score;
run;

data score_2018;
set score_2018 (rename=(student_id=old_id));
student_id=put(old_id, 8.);
drop old_id;
run;

data score_2019;
set score_2019 (rename=(student_id=old_id score=old_score));
student_id=put(old_id, 8.);
score=input(old_score, 8.);
drop old_id old_score;
run;
```

Two additional problem with the DATASTEP approach is that when I want to modify the type of a variable I need to write three procedures (rename, modify and drop (the old variable)) and the recoded variables are placed at the end of the file. When I recode only the first variable, as it is the case on the 2018 dataset, the order of the variables in the resulting dataset is different from the other datasets. So I thought this would be better done with `PROC SQL`.

But as I said, I have many variables and many years, so I wonder if it would be possible to write a macro to verify all variables and change their type (numeric or character) accordingly? For example, I want something like:

```
%macro recode;
PROC SQL;
%do year=1994 %to 2023;
create table score_&year. as
select
case when ISNUMBER(student_id)=1 then put(student_id, 8.) else student_id end as student_id,
case when ISNUMBER(score)=0 then input(score, 8.) else score end as score
from score_&year.;
%end;
quit;
%mend;
%recode;
```

I found the `ISNUMBER` function in some SAS forums, but my version of SAS (7.13) returns that  this function is unknown. I also tried `ISNUMERIC`, but I got the same error.

Comment: There is no SAS version 7.13.   That is probably the version of some tool you are using to submit the SAS code.

Comment: How did you get in this situation?  Can't you fix the step that is creating the individual datasets so they make the variables properly the first time?

Comment: It says here "Sas Enterprise Guide Version 7.13 HF5 (7.100.3.5486) (64-bit)". The datasets were generated by the government of my country and have this peculiarity. Apparently the people that are in charge each year feel like they need to change something in the data to "innovate"

Comment: Enterprise Guide is a tool for generating and submitting SAS code.  What functions you can use in the SAS code depends on the version of SAS itself that your EG session is using, not the version of EG that you are using.

Answer (score 3):

Create two lists, one of the datasets which contain `score` as a character, and another for datasets which have it as numeric.

```
proc sql ;
  select catx('.',libname,memname) into :CHAR_SCORE separated by ' '
  from dictionary.columns
  where libname = 'WORK'
    and memname like 'SCORE%'
    and name = 'SCORE'
    and type = 'char'
    ;

  select catx('.',libname,memname) into :NUM_SCORE separated by ' '
  from dictionary.columns
  where libname = 'WORK'
    and memname like 'SCORE%'
    and name = 'SCORE'
    and type = 'num'
    ;
quit ;
```

Then convert the character scores to numeric

```
data score_char_to_num (rename=(_score=score) drop=score);
  set &CHAR_SCORE ;
  _score = input(score,?? 8.) ;
run ;
```

Finally, stack the converted scores with the numeric ones...

```
data all_scores ;
  set score_char_to_num
      &NUM_SCORE
      ;
run ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the VALUE of an individual observation using the ISNUMBER() is not going to help with changing the variable type.  You need to look at the TYPE of the variable itself.  You could use something like this function style macro [%varexist()](https://github.com/sasutils/macros/blob/master/varexist.sas)

```
select 
  %if %varexist(score_2016,student_id,type)=C %then student_id else put(student_id,Z8.);
    as student_id
, %if %varexist(score_2016,score,type)=C %then input(score,32.) else score ;
    as score
from score_2016
```

But there are ways you could do it that does not need to know what type the existing variable is.  For example if you just rename ALL of the variables and then collapse the multiple variables into the one you want.

```
options missing=' ';
data want;
  length student_id $8 score 8;
  set score_2016 (rename=(student_id=id_2016 score=score_2016))
      score_2017 (rename=(student_id=id_2017 score=score_2017))
      score_2018 (rename=(student_id=id_2018 score=score_2018))
      score_2019 (rename=(student_id=id_2019 score=score_2019))
  ;
  student_id = put(input(cats(of id_:),32.),z8.);
  score = input(cats(of score_:),32.);
  drop id_: score_:;
run;
```